# Adding a view to node edit form

Tags: views, 8, forms

How to attach programmatically a view to the edit node form in Drupal 8?

In D7 I could achieve this by using this code

```
/**
 * Implements of hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

  // target a single form only
  if ($form_id == "form_id") {

    $form['html_markup'] = [
      '#markup' => views_embed_view('name_of_view','default'),
      '#weight' => 1
    ];    
  }
}
```

I'm looking for a way how can it implemented in D8.

Any tips will be appreciated!

Comment: What doesn't work about this? `hook_form_alter` was virtually unchanged for D8.

Answer (score 1):

I researched this for a while, then I found a sample implementation in `modules/views/tests/modules/views_test_data/src/Form/ViewsTestDataElementEmbedForm.php`:

```
$form['view'] = [
  '#type' => 'view',
  '#name' => 'test_view_embed',
  '#display_id' => 'embed_1',
  '#arguments' => [25],
  '#embed' => TRUE,
];
```

In that file it is used in `FormBase::buildForm`, but it works nicely also in `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`; I reported another example in [this comment to a similar post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111622/inserting-a-view-in-node-edit-form/279193#279193).

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 8 you can embed a view in two simple steps ,first get your desired view using `$myView = Views::getView('VIEW_NAME');` and then make a rendered output using `$rendered_view = $myView->buildRenderable('block_1',array($your_arguments));`, then you can attach it to your node edit form.